# How to make filter query in Django?

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-cms

I have the following *model.py*. I want to create a filter during Input. SubCategory automatically extracted from members Category. While the input current during subcategory will display the entire contents without filter. I want to choose one parent, then just out of the parent's members only.

```
> from django.db import models
> 
> > class Category(models.Model):
> >     name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
> >     
> >     def __unicode__(self):
> >         return self.name
> > 
> > class SubCategory(models.Model):
> >     name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
> >     category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
> >     
> >     def __unicode__(self):
> >         return self.name
> > 
> > class Input(models.Model):
> >     name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
> >     category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
> >     subcategory = models.ForeignKey(SubCategory)
> >     
> >     def __unicode__(self):
> >         return self.name
```

Comment: When you say 'during input', do you mean when you input data using django admin? Is it the django admin that you're trying to change?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [filter documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#filter).

To get a group of subcategories whose category field is populated by the category `my_cat`, you would do -

```
sub_cats = SubCategory.objects.filter(category=my_cat)
```

Comment: but its filter based on pre-selected categories above. Is Django can automatically show a sub menu of the parent members of the newly selected menu?