# filter in django 2.0

Tags: django, filter

Hey I am writing  app in django  many blogs with many articles each but i dont know how to take artices which belongs to blog and write filter

My articles model

```
class Articles(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name="Tytul")
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name="Tekst")
    published = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Data publikacji",auto_now=True)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="images",verbose_name="Obrazy",default=None)
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blogs,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
```

My blogs model

```
class Blogs(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name="Tytul")
    user = models.CharField(max_length=160, verbose_name="Uzytkownik")
```

blog.html

```
{% include 'base.html' %}
{% block blog %}

<h2>{{ blog.title }}</h2>
                    <div class="blog-info">
                        Tworca : {{ blog.user }}
                    </div>

{% block article %}
 {% for a in article.blog_set.all %} <---- here 

                   <div class="article">
                        Opublikowano : {{ a.published }}
                    </div>
                    <img src="{{ a.image.url }}" class="article-img">
                    <div class="article-intro">
                    <p>{{ a.content  }}</p>
                    </div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}


{% endblock %}
```

database[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make filter query in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13775505/how-to-make-filter-query-in-django)

Comment: Duplicate [filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13775505/how-to-make-filter-query-in-django)